# Are you wondering how a candidate’s score is calculated?

Tags: discussion, election

One bit of information voters might find helpful that I don't see linked anywhere obvious in the election pages is [how the candidate score is calculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/273494):

> The Candidate Score can range from 0 to 40, and is calculated as
> follows:
>
> - 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.
> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - Civic Duty, Cleanup, Deputy, Electorate, Marshal, Reviewer, Sportsmanship, Steward - for a maximum
>   of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - Copy Editor, Explainer, Organizer, Refiner, Strunk and White, Tag Editor - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - Constituent, Convention, Enthusiast, Investor, Quorum, Yearling - for a maximum of 6 points.
>
> For badges that can be awarded multiple times only 1 point is granted
> for each badge type, thus ensuring a maximum score of 40 points.
>
> Stats are calculated based on the current state of the candidate, so
> scores on past elections will not reflect the state of the candidates
> at the time the election was run.

(The original post has links to each of the badges that I didn't reproduce here)

There is [an SEDE query that will calculate the score for a given user id](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score). Keep in mind that SEDE isn’t updated in real time, so it’s not a perfect. You can find your user id for a site in the url for your profile on that site. Remember to change the site at the bottom of the query to the site you’re interested in.

Comment: @DialFrost You need to make sure the site you're running the query for (at the bottom) matches the user id you put in the box... For example, my user id on ELL would not work if the query was being run for Stack Overflow (the default)

Comment: @DialFrost For future reference, don’t add images with no image description to my posts.

Comment: [What's the point in adding alt-text to an image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144080/273494) [How to write good alt text](https://accessibility.huit.harvard.edu/describe-content-images)

Comment: Ah I understand now, Sorry for disrupting your post!

Comment: @DialFrost No worries. I appreciate the attempt to improve it.